# How to add an external folder to the class path?

Tags: java, maven

So I have the following folder structure:

- Project

  - lib
    (running jar from this folder)
  - properties (property file to load is in this folder)

I am trying to load a property file via X.class.getClassLoader().getResource("properties/fileName"). This method works in eclipse but when I build the jar using maven it fails to find the file, giving a file not found exception.

I suspect the folder is not in the classpath because if I run getClassLoader().getResources("") the property folder never shows up. I tried all the suggestions in previous questions on stackoverflow but none have worked so far.

I also tried running java -cp and -classpath but it still failed.

Answer (score 0):

When using Maven, files like `*.properties` and any other not-compilable files must lie at `src/main/resources` folder, by default, to be available.

Additionally, I would recommend you to use `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` to get a proper classloader, in order to load resources.

Anyway, if you want to have your custom folder at classpath, I suggest you to add as a resource, at the `pom.xml`, like this:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        ...
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <!-- The folder you want to be a resource (from project root folder), like: project/properties -->
                <directory>properties</directory>
                <!-- Filtering if Maven should post-process text files to find and replace ${key} params: in most cases, leave it false -->
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: When I try what you suggested, getClassLoader().getResources("") finds an URL but when it is passed into the FileInputStream constructor I get a file not found exception.

I wish I could use Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() but I'm stuck with legacy code...

Comment: I think your classloader isn't seeing the file. Isn't there any way to change the classloader? It could solve this problem for you... Anyway, I will take some time and check a workaround.

Comment: The classloader never sees the file because it isn't on the classpath no matter what I do. I wish I could change the classloader but I cannot. I did a work around where I no longer use the classloader so it is "fixed" for now. Thanks for the help, no need to waste your time.